# Taylor series in exponential curve (Desperate for help)

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion, approximation

I am a high school student writing a report about Newton’s law of cooling. Due to environnemental effect, the temperature of the environment might vary therefore I am planning on exploring how such problem could be applied and what math should be used.

Would it be possible to use Taylor series as we would expect a sine graph for the variation in temperature. Please let me know what you think and thanks a lot.

Website used for the idea: http://calculus7.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/nwtnslawcling1.pdf

Comment: You can always use a Taylor series, the question is why would you want to?

Comment: Wouldn’t we use it to get the best approximation for temperature?

Comment: Please let me know if I am wrong because I do not know a lot about math.

Comment: The Taylor series is a tool to approximate. Why do you want to approximate? If you know the temperature varies as a sine wave, you can use that to do your calculations directly, without the Taylor series.

Comment: Sorry for going off topic but how could I do the calculations directly?

Comment: Using the sine function? As in calculating what you want using the sine function. To be frank, I don't know what the topic is, and where your problem is. But at this stage, I'm almost certain you're putting the cart before the horse if you are worried about the Taylor series, unless you have a lot more work that you're not showing here at the moment.

Comment: @RubenKruepper, the idea is that I deriving the equation of newton’s law of cooling but my high school teacher said that it will be a bit easy to derive an equation that could easily be found online so therefore I am thinking of how to make my report a bit more difficult by adding more analysis. I thought of using Laplace transform but everyone on stack exchange disagreed. Now I found this website but I thought about using Taylor series because it is on my level and on the website the math looks a bit advanced. Anyway at the moment I have no clue on how to go and make my analysis on my level.

Comment: I have been researching for a week and seems like I can’t get any good answer so please @RubenKruepper, any help or guidance from you on how to go on with this essay will be very helpful(I have to submit this essay in less than 3 hours)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116773/discussion-between-ruben-kruepper-and-general-mo7).

Comment: Please @RubenKruepper, can you please answer my last question?

Comment: Hello again @RubenKruepper, do you mind checking?

Comment: Using variable names from wikipedia: $Q=hA(T(t)-T_{env}(t))$ now set $T_{env}(t) = \sin(ax)+b$ where $b$ is your average and $a$ defines your period. I don't know what you want to know, but you can just rearrange that statement to get $Q$ or $T(t)$ etc.

Comment: I beg you @RubenKruepper, can you carry it out in detail my deadline is in exactly an hour an a half for the report.

Comment: I just can’t figure it out

Comment: Omg I figured it out thanks a lot @RubenKruepper I was just panicing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116863/discussion-between-ruben-kruepper-and-general-mo7).

Comment: @Ruben Kruepper, please check the chat.